# I am facing some issue during pyrocms installation, Anyone can help me?

Tags: laravel, pyrocms

```
 I am using below command for installation: composer create-project pyrocms/pyrocms pyrocms-demo
```

But I am getting below error:

Potential causes:
- A typo in the package name
- The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your min
imum-stability setting
  see https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability for more det
ails.

Read https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md for further commo
n problems.
 To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
   - C:\xampp\php\php.ini
 You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PH
P in CLI mode.

Answer (score 1):

try this command without anything behind it:
`composer create-project pyrocms/pyrocms`

Answer (score 0):

I always use

```
$ composer create-project pyrocms/pyrocms .
```

when you are already inside the project root.

Also, check your system for requirements form here https://pyrocms.com/documentation/pyrocms/latest#installation/server-requirements